# Subclipse not recognizing my JavaHL

Tags: subclipse, eclipse-juno, ubuntu-12.10, javahl

I keep getting the following error:

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni"
```

Although the library path is correct:

```
user@localhost /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni $ ls -l
total 336
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Apr  6 02:06 libatk-wrapper.so -> libatk-wrapper.so.0.0.18
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Apr  6 02:06 libatk-wrapper.so.0 -> libatk-wrapper.so.0.0.18
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  85168 Sep 20  2012 libatk-wrapper.so.0.0.18
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Sep 28  2012 libsvnjavahl-1.so -> libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Sep 28  2012 libsvnjavahl-1.so.0 -> libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 256104 Sep 28  2012 libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0
```

The above was installed with `apt-get install libsvn-java` on ubuntu 12.10. [Basically this package here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/libsvn-java/filelist).

The installed version of svn is 1.7.5.

The installed version of subclipse is 1.8.19.

I understand that the required svn version for subclipse 1.8.x to work is 1.7.x.

How can I make subclipse recognize my installed JavaHL library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have found it...

The problem was in my `eclipse.ini` file, which looked like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-vmargs
-Djava.library.path="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni"
```

I had to remove the extra quotes: `-Djava.library.path="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni"` to `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni`.

That fixed it.